# basic button handler needs 2 clicks to actually work

Tags: c#, winforms, events, button, eventhandler

This is my first post here... I made my search work, but I'can't find a solution for this basic problem (still a C# newbee. Sorry, and thanks for your help): this basic button handler needs 2 clicks to actually work...

```
//button script
private void btnHp1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{btnHp1.Click += new EventHandler(btnTest_Click);}  

//handler for all buttons
void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)        
{
Button button = sender as Button;
MessageBox.Show(button.Name);
}
```

Comment: Add the event handler in the form's constructor or through the designer.

Comment: `btnHp1_Click` is your click handler. All you are doing here is using your handler to hook up another handler. On the second click you will fire `btnHp1_Click` (again), hook up `btnTest_Click` (again) and fire `btnTest_Click`. Your third click will probably end up firing `btnTest_Click` twice.

Comment: Thanks Bradley (and all), you are right. Your code does the trick. I guess l should also follow Matt's advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple example of what you want to achieve.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace StackOverFlow
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            btnHp1.Click += new EventHandler(btnTest_Click);
        }       

        void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button button = sender as Button;

            if (button != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(button.Name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or you can add the handler manually in the `InitializeComponent()` at the designer. something like :

```
private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            // Generated code
            btnHp1.Click += new EventHandler(btnTest_Click);
            // Generated code
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

From the way your functions are written, you probably intended to *call* `btnTest_Click` from inside `btnHp1_Click`, not attach another handler.

If so, the code should look like this:

```
//button script
private void btnHp1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   btnTest_Click(btnHp1, e);
}
```

What this function does, is basically forward the click event from `btnHp1` to `btnTest`, by overwriting the `sender`. When `btnTest` is clicked, the code in its direct handler will run.  When `btnHp1` is clicked, its direct handler simply calls the method that acts as the handler for `btnTest`, but overwrites the `sender` to make it look like the event originated in `btnHp1`.

This effectively gives you 2 buttons that do the same thing, with the same block of code.  That code is able to differentiate the 2 buttons based on their `Name` property.

If this isn't what you actually intended, let me know and I'll try to help your further.

Comment: Or just move the code from `btnTest_Click` to `btnHp1_Click`

Comment: I'm guessing he wants 2 different buttons to do the same thing, based on the fact that he is showing the button's Name property in a popup.

Comment: Yeah, although it is also possible that he is so new he is just seeing anything from a button to see how event handlers function.

Comment: In fact, I have 24 buttons to track and I just want to pass the button value to a unique handler wich involve many fonctions. I simplified the code here just to keep things short.

Comment: *I'm guessing he wants 2 different buttons to do the same thing,* In which case you just have both buttons connected to `btnHp1_Click`

Comment: There are *many* ways to do what it looks like he is trying to do.  I just picked the one that seemed closest to the code he had already written.

Comment: Having a function do nothing but call another function *with the exact same arguments* and the *exact same parameters* (there is no point doing `btnTest_Click(btnHp1, e);` because `sender` in this case should already be `btnHp1`) is just silly. Having 24 unique event handlers that all do exactly that is just needless code bloat. Have them all call the same handler directly.

Comment: Feel free to submit another answer with your method in it.  He only mentioned the 24 other buttons *after* I wrote this answer.  Your method is likely better, given that new information, anyway.